# G-WAN cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"

Tags: c++, g++, g-wan

I am starting to use gwan a lot. I'd like to use cpp but im getting a g++ error on Amazon:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
```

Is there any way of ignoring/skipping the directive on my side, or
specifying the g++ command line in a 'config' file?

(I like your use of directory names instead of config. - a simple effective
idea but what are my options here?)

Comment: It's `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` though both `0x` and `11` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often airing the question brings out the answer:

It looks like that the updated version of gcc (with 0x) on Amazon is called:

```
gcc44
```

Installing the most recent version did the job.